# Flutter FCM - Data messages are not always shown in background/terminated

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to implementing a notification feature in my app using firebase cloud messaging in flutter with only pure data messages without "notification". My backend uses .NET Core 6 with Firebase Admin SDK and i set Android Priority High, but even so message data notification does not always shows (sometimes it's shows, sometimes not).

PS: I'm using Flutter Local Notifications Plugin and i disabled battery optimisation for my app.

I tried to set priority high in notification payload, set channel priority high in AndroidManifest.